# How many times would you need to watch a movie to have seen every moment of it (i.e. not blinking)?

Tags: probability

Say we blink stochastically for .1 seconds every 4 seconds on average. How many times would we need to watch a 120 minute movie (assuming your eyes are glued to the screen the whole time), to have a 95% chance of seeing the entire movie?

How would I solve something like this?

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on your assumptions about blinking. If you (very unrealistically) model it as each frame (1/24th of a second) having iid 1/40 probability of blinking, the math is fairly straightforward. If you (more reasonably) model blinks as having exactly 0.1s duration with exponential waiting times in between (a Poisson process for the onsets), that's going to be harder.

Comment: Would love to see the easy way at least if you're game and (would love more to see the hard way)..

Comment: For the easy way: the time to see each frame is [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), and to see all the frames, watch the movie the max of all those variables times. You can find the cdf of the max by simply raising the cdf of an individual one to the number of frames. This expression isn't particularly nice analytically, but it's easy to handle numerically. You could also probably maybe get a reasonable bound for its expectation analytically. I don't have enough procrastination time right now to write it out, but let me know if you have trouble.

Comment: For the hard way: I don't really know how to approach it! (Except by numerical simulation.) It's related to, say, the sum of independent realizations of a Poisson process, which there are probably known results about, but I don't know a ton in this area.